# What is the Nunes Memo and what is preventing its release?

Tags: united-states, government

From what I've read (and please correct me if I'm wrong), Devin Nunes has created a memo that he wants to release but can't, for purposes that I do not know.

What's in the memo is **extremely important**, supposedly, and condemning of the FBI and surveillance methods.

I'm not entirely sure how it's related to the Mueller investigation (if it is) nor why Nunes couldn't release it himself (is it classified? I haven't seen anything to suggest it is).

I'm adding a CNN video where Adam Schiff references the memo:

[Memo alleges FBI Abuses](https://www.dailywire.com/news/26156/watch-adam-schiff-gives-insane-reason-why-ryan-saavedra)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The "Nunes Memo" is a [4-page document](https://lawfareblog.com/devin-nuness-mystery-memo-repeating-cycle-distraction) based on Republican congressman Devin Nunes' investigation that alleges that top FBI officials acted illegally to gain FISA warrants to conduct surveillance on the Donald Trump campaign. It is unclear what it says because it has not been released, supposedly because it reveals classified information about sources and methods that the FBI uses that might put those sources in danger or at least render them useless.

Some Republicans (not all) allege that it is ["bigger than Watergate"](http://thehill.com/policy/national-security/369851-fierce-battle-erupts-over-declassifying-intelligence-report?rnd=1516406309) and will bring the FBI down, resulting in prison for several top officials. [Others think that is way overblown](http://thehill.com/homenews/house/370287-top-house-judiciary-dem-rips-nunes-memo-accusing-fbi-of-bias). It possibly alleges that the FBI unethically (or illegally) used a source who was also on the Hillary Clinton campaign.

What is likely (and this is just my opinion) is that the FBI got a warrant to conduct surveillance on a Trump campaign official (Paul Manafort, Carter Page, or Michael Flynn), as plenty of them were engaged in questionable business activity with high-level Russian officials, and that this led to something else being found. Ultimately, we will not know until the memos get released, which he can do himself (although it may be a bit risky to go around customary channels) or get the President to do. At the moment of writing, he has not even shown it to the Justice Department, so who knows.

It is worth pointing out that, regardless of the potential veracity of its claims, this is entirely a partisan document. It was created in the House Intelligence Committee without input or consultation with the Democratic members of the committee, so the discussion of it once released is likely to be highly partisan.

Nunes, a former Trump campaign advisor, you might remember, was the person behind [the claim that Obama "wiretapped" the Trump campaign](https://www.axios.com/timeline-devin-nunes-and-trump-surveillance-claims-1513301236-c0c83abe-26be-4651-96b7-3dc84bbd203a.html), so this is likely an extension of that.

Comment: I concur. If it's the smoking gun that those Republicans say it is, it would derail the entire Mueller investigation. However, since the President can declassify any document he wants, it would seem odd that he wouldn't use that power to end the Russia collusion investigation on the spot.

Comment: The Washington Post just put up a general overview of the anti-anti-conspiracy theories that the Nunes memo is part of:  https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/politics/wp/2018/01/24/your-guide-to-the-anti-fbi-conspiracy-theories-rippling-through-conservative-media/?hpid=hp_hp-top-table-main_analysis-fbitheories-812am%3Ahomepage%2Fstory&utm_term=.0b837bbcd757

Comment: @WesSayeed He has had congressmen from both sides urging him to not fire Mueller, and I think he knows it would look VERY bad in the press.  So, instead, he and his allies have been attacking the investigation, trying to claim it is biased, almost from day one. I think they hope that if something ever really emerges, they can gain more by attacking and stalling than outright silencing.

Comment: As a bit of an update, the DOJ is telling the House that they should not release the memo yet.  Apparently, the House Intel Committee has not even shown it to the Senate Intel Committee, much less the DOJ and FBI.

Comment: Your wording here in the second paragraph can be a bit misleading. Since the subject of the first sentence is "Some Republicans" and the subject of the second is "Others," this I read the latter as meaning "Other Republicans." However, the linked article doesn't say any Republicans disagreed with it, but rather only that a single Democrat (Jerry Nadler) does.

Answer (score 10):

It is indeed classified, which means that the House Intelligence Committee will vote on the measure to release it and then, as long as the President approves, they will release it to the public.  Devin Nunes is not the only person who wants this memo released as about 180 signatories of a letter to Nunes (all Republicans) also express this interest.

While at this time it is to early to speculate, unnamed congressional sources say that the memo details abuses of the Foreign Intelligence Surveillance Act (FISA) by the Barack Obama administration in order to spy on the Donald Trump Campaign in the late stages of the 2016 election period (with possible speculation that this information was distributed to Trump's opposition, Hillary Clinton).  However, I will stress those are sources only.

Beyond speculative reporting, I do not know the contents of the memo nor would I guess as to what they will show once shown to the public.  Democrats on the Hill are trying to downplay the nature of the memo.

Comment: Are there any sources for it being classified?

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles:  http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/65-lawmakers-urge-devin-nunes-to-allow-release-of-memo-on-fisa-abuses/article/2646531   It's implied, but if it is derived from classified info, it becomes classified to the highest level of protection that the source material is classified to.

Comment: "it's implied" - well, that might be because that news source also wants to hype something that's not there.  The Examiner has a very decided political slant and agenda, so I'd want to stick with what's openly declared and their willingness to verify, not what they want to imply. Remember, the source of this memo has an established track record of making completely phony conspiracy-mongering statements.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet:  Allow me to rephrase:  The implication isn't from the article writer but the way the memo at question was created:  Nunes used classified sources, which means that the memo itself is classified to the highest level of the sources (at least).  The article doesn't say it, but it's easy to understand based on an understanding of how classified info works.

Comment: But we don't know that Nunes used classified sources, because we don't know anything more about the nature of this claim than we do his claim that Trump Towers was wiretapped. He may feel his large intestine is considered classified, so pulling stuff from there allows him to make that implied claim. Especially if his sources are no more authoritative than the usual gossip, saying they are "confidential" might be a way to give the *impression* that this is legitimate, classified stuff.  Certainly, the FBI, itself, would be cleared for this, and yet he won't give them the info.

Comment: We used to hear claims from conservative sources that they absolutely had video footage of Michelle Obama making radical "kill whitey" types of comments. And that, soon enough, we'd all see.  Except we never did because they made it all up.  Nunes made phony claims regarding wiretapping. Until someone, anyone besides Nunes actually sees what's in his memo and can validate or verify its legitimacy, it's all just innuendo.

Comment: Wait, is **Nunes** the only one who's seen/read his memo? The impression I got was that other members of Congress had seen it (ex. Schiff, in the video I posted seems to indicate that he's aware that the memo is based on *other material that the public is not aware of*). Or am I making too much out of the comments about the memo?

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles:  At least 65 house members have seen it and said that Nunes should release it according the article I sent you.  I recall a similar article saying it could now be as high as 180.  The linked article also says that those members who have read it have had to sign a waiver saying they will not disclose details BECAUSE IT IS BASED OFF OF CLASSIFIED SOURCES (and thus classified).

Comment: @PoloHoleSet:  https://www.cnn.com/2018/01/22/politics/gop-classified-intelligence-fisa-memo/index.html   Is CNN more to your accepted truthiness liking?  "On Thursday, the Intelligence Committee voted along party lines to allow all House members to view the four-page classified memo."

Comment: "Democrats say the findings are skewed and contain no more than Republican talking points." - so, no, that only confirms that the legitimacy of claims and that there is genuine classified intelligence to back it up remains completely unverified.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet:  So we must take everything Republicans say as false and everything Democrats say as True?  Because the OP only asked if it contained Classified Information, which I have provided two sources that say it does. The question was not "Is the intel being interpreted correctly OR are Republicans not releasing it because the Intel is false" which are not matters I am at present to address.  The OP only asks if the reason for it's controlled access is based on it's classified status, which I have twice cited sources that state that it is.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet:  The validity of Nunes' claims is not the at issue of fact to answer OP's question.  The fact that Nunes interpreted classified information to make whatever statements he makes in the memo (valid or not) is what is being asked.  Democrats can claim all they want, but Nunes is claiming that the memo cites classified information and thus is and of itself classified, which is why he cannot release it to the general population without taking the proper steps.  The document is classified, in so far as why Nunes does not show it, per OP's question.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet [CBS News](http://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/doj-tells-nunes-releasing-memo-would-be-extraordinarily-reckless/ar-AAv8Btx) also reports that a letter from the Assistant Attorney General also claims that the memo "likely contains highly classified information."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2018/01/25/republicans-full-steam-ahead-on-surveillance-memo-release-despite-doj-rebuke.html  Fox News actually quoted Ranking Committee member Shiff say it uses classified info:  “With this latest gambit, however, the Majority seeks to selectively and misleadingly characterize classified information in an effort to protect the President at any cost,” Schiff said in a statement.